# Can we modify Vuex action for jest unit testing?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

I've created a store in my test file

```
import {
shallowMount,
createLocalVue
} from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Actions from '../../../src/components/Actions'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Actions.vue', () => {
  let actions
  let store

beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
        actionClick: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({}))
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({
        actions
    })
})

it('should go to then block', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Actions, {
        store,
        localVue
    })
    //goes to then block
})

it('should go to catch block', () => {
    actions.actionClick = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error()))
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Actions, {
        store,
        localVue
    })
    //still goes to then block and not the catch block
  })
})
```

As per the code above the im not able to achieve the second test block means it is not modifying the actionClick function in store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeEach` hook happens before it goes into the `it` block. So the `store` setup is actually completed at this moment. As far as I can see from the `vuex` source, it detaches the action callbacks from the options object that you've passed to it at the creation step (`store = new Vuex.Store(...)`). You can check it [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js#L426).

So, I'd suggest you either creating new store object inside your `it` block:

```
it('should go to catch block', () => {
    actions.actionClick = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error()))
    store = new Vuex.Store({ actions })
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Actions, {
        store,
        localVue
    })
    //still goes to then block and not the catch block
  })
})
```

Or using `hotUpdate (newOptions)` method on the store instance. I didn't test this one. But, again, from the `vuex` [source](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js#L213) it is supposed to do exactly what you need.

```
it('should go to catch block', () => {
    actions.actionClick = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error()))
    store.hotUpdate({ actions })
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Actions, {
        store,
        localVue
    })
    //still goes to then block and not the catch block
  })
})
```

Comment: Wow `hotUpdate()` worked ! Thanks!
Is there any documentation ?

Comment: @aniket_777  In their API and a hot reload part. Here is the reference -> https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#hotupdate